# How to move a rectangle component in qml

Tags: c++, qml

How do I move a rectangle component in Qml using c++ program, it has to progress from minimum to maximum value like a progress bar with color gradient. i have tried to use number animation and it is working fine,but how do i change the color as it progresses.

Comment: How do you move the rectangle? Post some appropriate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a specific answer as you've not provided much detail or a code sample. However it seems like you want to set the color property of your progress bar rectangle to be dependent on it's width or position, so that it changes depending on how much 'progress' has been made.

In addition, you may be able to use a [ColorAnimation](http://ColorAnimation) class to animate this, along with a Behaviour, for example:

```
Rectangle {
    id: progressBar
    width: 0
    height: 20
    color: (width < 30) ? "red" : (width < 60) ? "yellow" : "green"

    Behavior {
        ColorAnimation { target: progressBar; duration: 500 }
    }
}
```